# Ngrx fetch data only if store is empty

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

Let's assume in my application I have 3 pages: Faculties,Groups,Specialities.

This is how interface for these entities looks like:

```
interface Faculty {
  faculty_id: number;
  faculty_name: string;
  faculty_description: string;
}
interface Speciality {
  speciality_id: number;
  speciality_code: string;
  speciality_name: string;
}
interface Group {
  group_id: number;
  group_name: string;
  speciality_id: number;
  faculty_id: number;
}
```

When I go to page Faculties in `ngOnInit` I'm checking boolean property in the FacultyState, If faculties  has already been loaded then do not dispatch action else in Effect the service will make  http request.

The same I've done for Speciality page.

### Faculty component (Speciality also similar)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.store.pipe(
          select(areFacultiesLoaded),
          tap((hasLoaded) => {
            if (!hasLoaded) {
              this.store.dispatch(loadAllFaculties())
            }
          })
        ).subscribe();
    
    
       this.faculties$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectAllFaculties))
      }
```

### Effect

```
@Injectable()
export class FacultyEffects {
    loadFaculties$ = createEffect(() => {
        return this.actions$.pipe(
                ofType(FacultyAction.loadAllFaculties),
                concatMap(() => {
                   return this.apiService.getEntity('Faculty').pipe(
                        map(data => FacultyAction.allFacultiesLoaded({ faculties: data })),
                        catchError(() => EMPTY)
                        )}
                    ),
        );
    });
```

### The problem

For example I can go to the group page first which also needs faculties and specialties.

1. Should I again check If faculties and specialities  have been
   loaded?
2. Should I create another action for groups for example - [Groups
   page] fetch all Faculties(Specialities)
3. Should I create another effects for those actions?

Answer (score 2):

See https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#4-using-a-selector-inside-your-effects fore more info

```
@Effect()
getOrder = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType<GetOrder>(ActionTypes.GetOrder),
  withLatestFrom(action =>
    of(action).pipe(
      this.store.pipe(select(getOrders))
    )
  ),
  filter(([{payload}, orders]) => !!orders[payload.orderId])
  mergeMap([{payload}] => {
    ...
  })
)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify one thing? what happens when data is already loaded. This effect will not fire any resultant action so don't we need dispatch: false otherwise the incoming action will be re-dispatched resulting in an infinite loop according to your article.

Comment: not really, the filter prevents that the action is passed down in the pipeline. if filter emits false, this snippet doesn't (re)fire an action